# How to override python package version constraint during pip install

Tags: python, pip

We have an organization level [constraint file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files) to specify what versions of python packages can be installed. This is configured in pip.conf

For one of the project, we want to install a different version of a package.
For example, pyyaml is pinned at 5.4.1 in constraints file, whereas for the project we would like 6.0

Tried specifying inline in pip install command,

```
pip install pyyaml==6.0
```

This didn't help as the build failed with conflict error,

> ERROR: Cannot install pyyaml==6.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
>
> The conflict is caused by:
> The user requested pyyaml==6.0
> The user requested (constraint) pyyaml==5.4.1

```
pip version: 21.3.1
```

Comment: Have you tried `--isolated` on the `pip` command line? According to the help, it then `[ignores] environment variables and user configuration.`

Comment: @FlyingTeller that flag ignores configs entirely not just the version constraint, which is not what I want. I guess I just have to have a constraint file specific for the project and replace the one already in place.

Answer (score -2):

```
# constrains.txt
   pyyaml==5.4.1
```

```
$ pip install pyyaml==6.0 -c constrains.txt
```

Comment: This does not work, at least not on `pip 22.3`: ERROR: Cannot install pyyaml==6.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested pyyaml==6.0
    The user requested (constraint) pyyaml==5.4.1